# A general wavefunction in a square lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, wavefunction

Suppose we have a square lattice with periodic condition in both $x$ and $y$ direction with four atoms per unit cell, the configuration of the four atoms has $C_4$ symmetry. What will be a general wavefunction in this lattice look like? How will it different from the usual Bloch wavefunction?

Comment: What do you mean different from the "usual Bloch wavefunction"? Are you asking about the effect of the $C_4$ symmetry? Or are you confused about having multiple atoms in a tight binding description? Or some combination thereof?